# Displaying content on top of an edge in Cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

In my graph, each node would represent a state and the edges are allowed transitions between those states.  I also allow there to be actions that are performed when there is a transition from one state to another, so the actions are attached to the edge between the two states.  I'm trying to figure out a way to visualize those actions on the edges.  It seems the only thing I can put on an edge is a label using the `content` of the styling.  I had hoped that I could set `content` to a function to allow me to return some html content, but that doesn't seem to work. Is there another way I could do this?  I had also thought of possibly creating nodes between the state nodes, but with there only being one `nodes` collection, these new nodes would be mixed with the actual nodes and complicate things.  I'm also using the context menus, so I could pop up "View Actions" off the edge, but I still need a way to visually show that action exist on an edge.  If anyone has ideas on how to visualize this, please let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HTML content can not be rendered inside a canvas.  Labels are merely drawn using `context.fillText()`.

If you want to display HTML content, you will need to put that content in your page's HTML.  You could create a Cytoscape.js extension to make this easier or more concise in your code, but the organisation is completely your choice.

I would create an extension that renders HTML labels using a div on top of the Cytoscape.js canvases.  You could sync the positions with `viewport` events.  If you take this approach, you may want to co-ordinate with John Wehr, who has started an extension to do just that: https://github.com/wehriam/cytoscape-css-renderer

This discussion may also be of interest to you: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/305